# How to find element which has 2 classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find a element which has 2 classes

for example

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
```

here I want to apply different CSS for both the div, but both have class name as **"class1"**

Comment: `.class1.class2 { }`.

Comment: no, different css for both the div

Comment: You want to add styles in JS and can not define it in css?

Comment: What is it that you want to do with what you have found? Apply styles? Or something else? Did you think about `:not`?

Comment: If both div has different parent you can use parent class name .parent .class1{}

Comment: Please show the exact code structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the DIVs using javascript and loop through them, check the class names and apply the css accordingly

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
div.forEach(function(d){
    debugger;
  if(d.className === "class1") {
    // css for class1
  } else if(d.className === "class1 class2") {
    // css for class2
  }  
});
</script>
```

OR Using Css

```
.class1 {
   background-color: red;
}

.class1.class2 {
   background-color: blue;
}
```